# Return only matching sub document from MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb

We have following structure in our Mongo collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f98aeadbaf1ea001affe4c0"),
    "name" : "Temp",
    "campaigntype" : 3,
    "startdate" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "enddate" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "affiliatetag" : "",
    "promotedtitles" : [ 
        {
            "primaryisbn" : "9781453238431",
            "promoprice" : "1.99",
            "countries" : [ 
                "US", 
                "CA", 
                "AU", 
                "GB"
            ],
            "retailers" : [ 
                "ALL"
            ],
            "dlp" : "17.99",
            "notes1" : "History",
            "notes2" : "",
            "sequence" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "primaryisbn" : "9781504063562",
            "promoprice" : "1.99",
            "countries" : [ 
                "US", 
                "CA"
            ],
            "retailers" : [ 
                "ALL"
            ],
            "dlp" : "11.99",
            "notes1" : "Thrillers",
            "notes2" : "",
            "sequence" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "primaryisbn" : "9781497673984",
            "promoprice" : "0.99",
            "countries" : [ 
                "US", 
                "CA"
            ],
            "retailers" : [ 
                "ALL"
            ],
            "dlp" : "6.99",
            "notes1" : "Romantic Suspense",
            "notes2" : "",
            "sequence" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "primaryisbn" : "9780547526959",
            "promoprice" : "1.99",
            "countries" : [ 
                "CA"
            ],
            "retailers" : [ 
                "All"
            ],
            "dlp" : "17.99",
            "notes1" : "History",
            "notes2" : "",
            "sequence" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "primaryisbn" : "9781453274248",
            "promoprice" : "1.99",
            "countries" : [ 
                "US"
            ],
            "retailers" : [ 
                "All"
            ],
            "dlp" : "9.99",
            "notes1" : "Historical Fiction",
            "notes2" : "",
            "sequence" : 5
        }
    ],
    "active" : true,
    "createdby" : ObjectId("5d2e2755d3851f0012108a05")
}
```

We need to write a query by passing single country like ['US'] or multiple country like ['US', 'CA']. Query should only return us matching sub document from promoted titles.

For example, If we pass country as 'US', we should get primary isbn 9781453238431, 9781504063562, 9781497673984 and 9781453274248. If we pass country as ['GB', 'CA'], we need to get 9781453238431, 9781504063562, 9781497673984 and 9780547526959. If we pass ['GB'], we should only get 9781453238431 sub document

We were trying with promotedtitles.countries : {$in : ['US', 'CA']} but that don't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try that?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element

Comment: We did. It will work for single field lf we pass "US" or "GB" and it will still return all sub document where as we only wanted to fetch matching sub document. We also tried elemMatch but that only returns first matching sub document which don't full fill our requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$unwind` and `$match` like this:

- `$unwind` is to deconstruct the array and get every object as a different value instead all together in an array.
- Then you can filter each object using `$match` and `$in`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$promotedtitles"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "promotedtitles.countries": {
        "$in": [
          "US"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "result": "$promotedtitles.primaryisbn"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6egH57xV_9V) using `US` and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiO-a1DG6kU) with `GB, CA`.

Also, if you want to get all ISBNs in an array you can add a `$group` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCb-O-asKaO)